# php code to Display Monthly Booking Report using sql

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a Surveyor Management System in php using Mysql DB. I am stuck in my Project. Please anybody suggest How to Achieve This.

Now I want to display a report of all Surveyor Booking Count for the current month.

**FOR EX -**

IN MY Form there are two filters.

1)  FromDate   2)  TODATE

If User Select fromdate = 01-03-2015  AND Todate = 25-03-2015

Then Print All Date Between 01-03-2015 AND 25-03-2015 in header.

AND Display surveyorname And their  total below particular date.

I have written sql query to display the result here is:

```
 <?php
if($_POST && isset($_POST['Submit']))
{               
    if($_POST['fromdate']!='' && $_POST['todate']!='')
    {   
    $fromdate = $_POST['fromdate']; 
    $todate = $_POST['todate'];
    $data = $database->getRows("select surveyor_name,count(DISTINCT receipt_no) As total from receipt_entry WHERE bookingdate BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate
     group by surveyor_name,bookingdate"
    ,array(':fromdate'=>$fromdate,':todate'=>$todate));
    }   


}
?>
```

But I want to display in 31 days table manner by taking only Date in table.

How can I do this in php mysql..

**Below is my expected output.**

```
SurveyorName   01-03-2015   02-03-2015    03-03-2015   04-03-2015  05-03-2015   06-03-2015 07-03-2015 08-03-2015 09-03-2015 10-03-2015 11-03-2015 12-03-2015 13-03-2015 14-03-2015 15-03-2015 16-03-2015 17-03-2015 18-03-2015 19-03-2015 20-03-2015 21-03-2015 22-03-2015 23-03-2015 24-03-2015 25-03-2015 26-03-2015 27-03-2015 28-03-2015 29-03-2015 30-03-2015

lucky           2                 5           0            0           0            0        0          0                 0           0       0         0          0                    0         0         0                 0           0        0 ..... ....etc.

raj             5                 1           0        0       etc.
```

Comment: This is a very broad question, unfortunately. Let me tell you some jargon so you can break it down into smaller pieces.  First, you are fetching detail records that INTERSECT a range of dates. Second, you are trying to fill in missing dates in your ranges somehow. Third, you are *pivoting* your dates from rows to columns.

Comment: I Only Need To display pivot Dates and below this dates the Total of Particular dates...thats it...

Comment: is this is possible  using sql and php